# How to store video path in database and play video in browser using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, video-streaming

I would like to upload video path in database and it play video in my browser using asp.net and sql server.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. At first you must create table in DB ( it can very simple table, just ID and video path ). Than, you must insert record into DB using OLE DB. TO show you video you must pull back video path and add it to you player on page. You must use google to search, there a plenty solutions on the internet.